# PHP Битрикс: как отключить скрытую копию для одного шаблона?

Tags: php, битрикс

**Ситуация:**

1) Я - новичок в битриксе, один из первых заказов. Но есть опыт в PHP (Yii2 и самописные).
2) В настройках главного модуля прописан адрес в поле "E-Mail (или список через запятую), на который будут дублироваться исходящие сообщения"
3) Заказчик хочет, чтобы пара шаблонов не приходила на данный ящик в качестве скрытой копии.
4) У меня есть доступ к файлу со строкой ниже и код править могу.

```
CEvent::Send("SUBSCRIBE_CONFIRM", $SITE_ID, $arFields);
```

Но подставить "N" четвертым аргументом я не могу, т.к. модуль subscribe стандартный.

**Вопрос:**

Как можно в этих условиях убрать рассылку скрытой копии для одного почтового шаблона или одного почтового события?

Answer (score 0):

Всё это вы сможете настроить административную часть. Смотрите в шаблонах почтовых сообщений. У вас есть модуль subscribe, который использует какойто почтовый шаблон, в котором вы можете указать куда будут приходить письма, а также скрытые копии и многое другое.